# При открытии сайта через IDE (Brackets) сайт отображается нормально, но если напрямую, то не отображаются изображения

Tags: google-chrome, изображения, ide, img, brackets

```css
<style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fbdb9e;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; }

nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; }
  nav > div {
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; }
    nav > div > a {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      padding: 3vw 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 1vw;
      font-weight: 600; }
      nav > div > a:hover {
        border-bottom: 0.4vw solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4); }

.current {
  border-bottom: 0.4vw solid white; }

.division_line {
  border: 0.03vw solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 40%; }
    #border-width{
         border: 3px double black;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-color: red;
       padding: 2%
    }
.short {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
    }
  .short > div {
    width: 40%;
    font-size: 1vw;
    font-weight: 400; }
  
    .footer{
        background-color: #fbdb9e;
        height: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 2px solid black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .span{
        color: red;
        font-size: 125%;
    }
    #image{
        width: 76%;
        height: 60%;
        right: 90%;
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

    </head>
    <body>

<nav>
    <div>
        <a href="%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0.html" class="current"><span>Начальная страница</span></a>
        <a href="История создания.html">История создания &quot;Мертвые души&quot;</a>
        <a href="index.html">Краткий сюжет</a>
        <a href="Герои романа.html">Герои романа</a>
        <a href="Галерея.html">Галерея</a>
    </div>
</nav>

<div  class="short">
    
       <p>
    <img id="image" src="/images/Heroes/fone.png"/>
</p>
<br>
<footer class="footer short">
  <a style="text-decoration: none" href="О нас.html"><span class="span">О нас</span></a> 
</footer>
</html></body>
```

Comment: структуру каталога проекта покажите, просто скриншот  - т.е надо знать как расположена папка images относительно index.html

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/8ZafoH0k3UHMZ2 там скрины

Comment: url будет таким images/Heroes/fone.png